# On hover, line should turn red start from left to right. When remove mouse it should reverse

Tags: html, css

[CSS animation, help requred, On hover, line should turn red start from left to right. When remove mouse it should reverse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7VeC.png)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dct34.png

Comment: Where your tried markup??

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dct34.png

Comment: Ganesh, you need to share your code with us. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, we aren't going to write this for you from scratch. Give it a shot and let us know what problems you encounter and maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```css
ul {
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  list-style:none;
}
ul li {
  display:block;
}
ul li a {
  text-decoration:none;
  padding:10px;
  position:relative;
  transition:all 0.3s linear
}
ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration:none;
}
ul li a:after {
  content:'';
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  bottom:0px;
  width:0px;
  height:1px;
  background:tomato;
  transition:all 0.3s linear
}
ul li a:hover:after {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```